# Why there are so much Tor IPs blacklisted?

Tags: torcheck

Yeah, the onion routing is in my opinion a fantastic concept. However I don't understand why Tor is offerng a blacklist of the exit Nodes/ IP. Everywehrer in the web Tor IPs ar blocked and you have to deal with captchas.

For example I've found not even one Mail provider who is not blocking Tor. So if I want mail fairly anonymous, also with Enigmail and  GnuPGP, I need a mail provider. And theta provider I want to join with Tor, but yeah-> blocked.

Just everywhere on the web Tor IPs are blocked.

Comment: the answer is in the FAQs of the Tor project: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#HideExits

Answer (score 6):

Did you hear about the millions of people that ride motorcycles safely to work and then home every day? Yeah, probably not - I didn't either, but I did hear about that horrible accident, and that made me worry about motorcycles being safe.

The fact of the matter is, of all the people using Tor, you *never* hear about the good things that Tor users do for sites, just like this one. You only hear about the spammers, trolls and psychopaths that use the service as a way to evade efforts to keep them from creating the disruptions that they do.

We (Stack Exchange) do *not* block Tor exit nodes, but a considerable number of them are currently being tracked by our spam prevention and abuse mitigation systems simply because Tor is a tool that does not discriminate against endeavor - a lot of people up to no good happen to use it because it fits their particular need quite well.

It makes me sad that the *few* - those that feel enabled or *entitled* to be complete and total miscreant jerks can result in such an inconvenience for those that simply want to not be tracked, but it's unfortunately the way that it is, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

Transparency is an important aspect of Tor's design. Information about all relays (except bridges) is available for public review. Information about bridges is not published, in order to help protect them against censors. It's arguable that exit IPs should also remain private. But that would frustrate public review of exit ownership.

VFEmail welcomes Tor users, and provides a hidden service portal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - they want to prevent abuse, or they for some reason feel the need to be able to trace users back to their IP.

Anonymity often attracts abuse, and one way to counter that (easily) as a web service provider is to simply block all the exit nodes - or 'catch' them with captcha's and so on to try to prevent bots from entering data and so on.